# exercise 1.17 in francis text functional analysis, calculus of variations and optimal control theory

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi: This is an exercise in the functional analysis introduction in the text stated in the title. It's not homework. I'm just reading the book  ( to annoy myself :) )  and figure that, if I don't get something early, I'm not going to get the more difficult concepts.

The exercise states: Let $\Lambda = L(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two normed spaces.

Then, define the following norm.

$||T || := || \Lambda || = \underset{ x \in X, ||x|| \le 1} {sup} || \Lambda(X) ||_{Y} ~~~(3.1.4) $

Also, put:

$   A := || \Lambda || = \underset{ x \in X, ||x|| = 1} {sup} || \Lambda(X) ||_{Y}   ~~~(3.1.5) $

$ B:=  || \Lambda || = \underset{ x \in X, x \neq 0 } {sup} \frac{|| \Lambda(X) ||_{Y}}{||x||_X}  ~~~(3.1.6) $

Then $||T|| = A = B$. Does anyone know how to prove it or know where a proof might be ? I've looked around and couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional analysis, you only need to know what a supremum is. For example, given a non-empty bounded set of real numbers $A$, you need to know that in order to prove an inequality of the form $\sup(A) \leq x$ is sufficient to verify that $a \leq x$ for all $a \in A$. Use this to check for example that $$\sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|\Lambda(x)\|_Y}{\|x\|_X} \leq \sup_{\|x\|_X = 1} \|\Lambda(x)\|_Y.$$

Comment: @azif100: Are you saying that , since the denominator of the left hand side can be greater than 1.0,  that makes the thing on the left hand side ( without the sup) definitely less than or equal to the right hand side which makes the statement true ? If so, I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: What if the denominator is not greater than 1? You need to start with $x \in X$, $x \neq 0$, and then prove that $$\frac{\|\Lambda(x)\|_Y}{\|x\|_X} \leq \sup_{\|v\|_X=1} \|\Lambda (v)\|_Y.$$ I don't see how your argument proves this.

Comment: @azif00: good point so what is the argument ? I'm sure it's basic for some but I don't see it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is interested,  I found the following proof on the internet in a chapter ( from a text ) titled "operators on normed spaces" by Dzung Minh Ha. It is from his "Introduction to Functional Analysis" book which looks very good at a glance. Unfortunately, the text is currently only available as an ebook. It is published by a company called MatrixEditions which has a website called MatrixEditions.com.

Proof: Assume that $X \neq \{0\}$. It's clear that $A \le ||T||$. Let $x \in X$ and $x \neq 0$. Then $ z := \frac{x}{||x||}$ has norm 1 so that

$\frac{||Tx||}{||x||} = ||T x|| \leq A.  ~~~(3.1.7)$

This shows that $B \leq A$. Conversely, if $||x|| = 1$, then $||Tx|| =  
\frac{||Tx||}{||x||} \leq B$ so that $A \leq B$. Hence $A = B$. Finally,
(3.1.7) shows that $||Tx|| \leq A||x|| \leq A$ if $||x|| \leq 1$. Thus
$||T|| \leq A$. So $||T|| = A$.